# Split long string WP7

Tags: c#

How do I split a long string ?

Input :

```
ABCDEFGHI
```

Output :

```
ABC, DEF, GHI
```

Comment: Another wonderful way of doing things would be to check the list on the right. From my view, seven of the first ten questions are related to splitting a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
string str = "ABCDEFGHI";

List<string> lst = new List<string>();

string temp = "";

for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    temp = str[i].ToString();

    if((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
    {
        lst.Add(temp);
        temp = "";
    }
}

string final_str = string.Join(", ", lst);
```

Comment: Thank for your comment, but I have 2 error :

`The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments`

and


`cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string[]'`

Comment: Change last line string.Join(", ", lst.ToArray());

Comment: Thank you, Nikhil Agrawal. 
But output is : `C, F, I`
Not the same output : `ABC, DEF, GHI`

Comment: Found the culprit. Change first line in loop to `temp += str[i].ToString();`. This will correct it. Moreover accept my answer after this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a very long string, use a string builder to do your concatenating.  And use substring to build the individually grouped strings.  This will save you on memory.

```
string longString = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
int groupingLength = 3;

var stringLength = longString.Length;
var startingLength = Math.Min(longString.Length, groupingLength);
var startingString = longString.Substring(0, startingLength);
var sb = new StringBuilder(startingString);
if (stringLength > groupingLength)
{
    for(int i = groupingLength; i < stringLength; i = i + groupingLength)
    {
        var subStringLength = Math.Min(stringLength - i, groupingLength);
        var groupedString = longString.Substring(i, subStringLength);
        sb.Append(", ").Append(groupedString);
    }
}
var finalString = sb.ToString();
```